# How to find the version of Wayland?

Tags: wayland

I'm unsure how to let devs know which version of the Wayland display server I'm running in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. How can I get the proper version for Wayland? Is it just the package version?

Answer (score 4):

There is no Wayland display server. Wayland is a protocol. The compositor is the closest thing you get to a display server. In Gnome, that's mutter. So in Ubuntu, you'd probably do something like `apt-cache show mutter | grep Version`.

Comment: ```jrd_10@my-pc:~$ apt-cache show mutter | grep Version
Version: 42.5-0ubuntu1
Version: 42.0-3ubuntu2```

I have two... versions? (On ubuntu 22.04.1)

Answer (score -1):

You can see what [version of Gnome](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/gnome-version.html.en) you are currently running, as this often used for reference when talking about gnome-shell extensions and other Wayland related software issues, by opening the Activities panel and searching for `about` which will load the about tab of your settings panel, Gnome version will be listed
[image: About tab in Settings panel]

Alternatively, a quick way to get the servion from a terminal is by listing the currently installed `gnome-desktop` package

```
> apt-get list gnome-desktop3-data #on debian
gnome-desktop3-data/byzantium,now 3.38.5-3pureos1 all [installed,automatic]
```

in this case I have the `v3.38.5`.  On other distros the desktop package has a different name,

```
 > apt-get list ubuntu-gnome-desktop #on ubuntu
```

on other distros you'll need to search which package include the core Gnome desktop files.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04.1, on this works
```> xxx@my-pc:~$ sudo apt list ubuntu-gnome-desktop
> Listing... Done
> ubuntu-gnome-desktop/jammy 0.92 amd64```